# putting spaces in same line for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have an assignment for programming, and I'm having trouble. I'm 99% done but it's the little things that are tripping me up. Here is my code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

for h in first:
    a = LetterMap[h]

    print(a,end="")         

for h in middle:
    b = LetterMap[h]
    print(b,end="")

for c in last:
    c = letterMap[c]
    print(c,end="")
```

The output before this block and this block is this:

```
first middle last

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like it to be this:

```
first middle last

xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx
```

Comment: Just add a `print(" ", end="")` before the 2nd and 3rd loop?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to "declare variables at the top" like you're doing; this isn't C.

Comment: You should have a capital L on last `LetterMap`. Maybe I am dense because everyone else seems to know, but where are the values set for the variables `first,middle,last`? Does `first = "first"`, presumably? If so can you do `for h in "first":`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for h in first:
    a = LetterMap[h]
    print(a,end="")

print(" ",end="")

for h in middle:
    b = LetterMap[h]
    print(b,end="")

print(" ",end="")

for c in last:
    c = letterMap[c]
    print(c,end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than printing out your characters one by one, I'd suggest using `str.join` and generator expressions to combine your translated sequences into strings:

```
first_str = "".join(LetterMap[c] for c in first)
middle_str = "".join(LetterMap[c] for c in middle)
last_str = "".join(LetterMap[c] for c in last)
```

Then you can print them with just one `print` call:

```
print(first_str, middle_str, last_str) # default separator is a space!
```

If you wanted some more sophisticated formatting of the output (rather than just spaces separating the values), you can use the `str.format` method to do whatever kind of formatting you want:

```
print('{2:<20}{1:_^20}{0!r:*>20}'.format(first_str, middle_str, last_str)
```

That will print the strings in "reverse" order, with the "last" one left-justified in a width-20 column, the middle value centered in a width-20 column with underscores padding it on each side, and a representation of the "first" value (with quotes and backslash escapes, as needed) on the right of the final 20-wide column padded with asterisks.

For example, if you three strings were `'foo'`, `'bar'` and `'baz'`, you'd get:

```
baz                 ________bar_________***************'foo'
```

You can read about the string formatting mini-language [in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).